# Defining a goal that can be achieved through many ways

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I want to define a goal that can be achieved through many ways. 
Does *multidirectional* work?  "A multidirectional goal"?

It's for a title of an essay saying that there is not just a single way to stay healthy, but health is a single goal which can be achieved by multiple routes.

Comment: mutlidirictional is not a word.

Comment: How could i best describe it please?

Comment: @ nina: I think medica just means you spelt *multidirectional* wrong. I've made a few other changes to your text, but feel free to change anything back if you feel I've misrepresented your question.  FWIW I can't think of a suitable word - but the concept you're after seems clear enough to me, so it's quite likely there *is* something.

Comment: _multi-path_ might work but it is used a technical term mainly. (as in "multi-path solution"). It would be better to define with many words instead of trying to fit a single word that might not be understood.

Answer (score 2):

How about a [multifaceted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/multifaceted) [approach](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/approach): having many facets or aspects as a way or means of reaching something:

> - Cancer Immunotherapy Takes a *Multi-Faceted Approach* to Kick the Immune System into Gear.
> - The Importance of a *Multifaceted Approach* in the Assessment and Treatment of Childhood Feeding Disorders

Answer (score 1):

[There is more than one way to skin a cat](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/There%27s+more+than+one+way+to+skin+a+cat) and there is more than one way to lose fat.

And then I would also offer [All roads lead to Rome](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/All+roads+lead+to+Rome) which could probably stand by itself in your writing or you could pun it up with All roads lead to Health.

> There are many different routes to the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

here is a word not recognized by Oxford but found in several dictionaries and fits you need, in a way:

multivious - having many ways or roads.

search Merriam Webster's online dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially state it as simply as you did in your explanation:

*"The Many Solutions to Good Health"*

I'm not sure that you'll find one word that explains your intent that will also be understood immediately by most audiences.

That exact title probably won't work for you, but I'm just trying to make the point that simpler can be better.